# How to detect if I click on an object (2D) using Raycast?

Tags: unity

I need to know this for a little popup I made in my game, I want to avoid using `OnMouseDown` because I have multiple cameras so I was wondering how I'd be able to detect a mouse click event on an object using `Raycasting`, as I can't figure it out :/

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Add a physics raycaster to your camera and an EventSystem to your scene, then  implement the IPointerX (up, down etc) handler in your script.